# Is it possible to aggregate a table while joining in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am in the process of creating a star schema from a relational database. In the original database, there are three separate each with a related quantity field. The first two tables are 1:1. The third table has potentially many rows for each row of the first two tables. The values in the quantity fields for the first two tables can be matched directly against the other, but the values in the last table need to be summed on the case key associated with the row in the first two tables. Is it possible to do this in the join statement?

For example, we'll call the three tables PO (Purchase Order Data), IN (Invoice Data), and LI (Line Item Data).

```
Create Table CASES AS (
SELECT
PO.CASE_KEY
PO.QUANTITY
IN.QUANTITY
SUM(LI.QUANTITY)
FROM CASES
LEFT JOIN PO ON 1=1
AND CASES.CASE_KEY = PO.CASE_KEY
LEFT JOIN IN ON 1=1
AND PO.CASE_KEY = IN.CASE_KEY
LEFT JOIN LI ON 1=1
AND IN.CASE_KEY = LI.CASE_KEY)
```

Should this rough format work, or is some kind of group by required? At the moment, without the sum wrapped around LI.QUANTITY in the SELECT statement, only one of the potentially many associated quantity values in the LI table are pulled into the new case table. How can I get the join to sum these values?

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what the query should be doing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, rather than

```
LEFT JOIN LI ON 1=1
AND IN.CASE_KEY = LI.CASE_KEY)
```

You would use a derived table like so

```
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT
    LI.CASE_KEY
    ,SUM(LI.QUANTITY) AS total
  FROM
    LI
  GROUP BY
    LI.CASE_KEY
) AS lisum
  ON lisum.CASE_KEY = IN.CASE_KEY
  AND 1=1
```

And then your top select would reference lisum.total rather than SUM(LI.QUANTITY)

With this approach, you are aggregating the table by the case_key and then it's the results of that which you are joining to the rest of the query.

Comment: This worked exactly as needed. Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: @ah_tatatatatata Glad to hear it, if you could mark my answer as the accepted answer too then others will know which answer solved the problem for you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is certainly a way to do what you want.

First I notice you are querying the table `CASES` while you are inserting into `CASES`.  I'm going to ignore that since I don't understand it.  Also I will just focus on the `SELECT` which you can use in your `Create Table` statement.

I notice you are doing a `LEFT JOIN ON 1=1 AND ...`
but since `1=1` is just always true you don't need to AND it.

What you want to do is group by the columns in the `PO` and the `IN` tables.  You will likely need all the non-aggregated columns in the `SELECT` clause.

That would give you this:

```
SELECT PO.CASE_KEY, PO.QUANTITY, IN.QUANTITY, SUM(LI.QUANTITY)
FROM PO
  LEFT JOIN IN ON PO.CASE_KEY = IN.CASE_KEY
  LEFT JOIN LI ON IN.CASE_KEY = LI.CASE_KEY
GROUP BY PO.CASE_KEY, PO.QUANTITY, IN.QUANTITY
```

This will give you a row for every combination of `PO` and `IN` with the sum of the `QUANTITY` on the related `LI` records.  When there is a `PO` record with no `IN`, there will be a row, will NULL for the `IN.QUANTITY` column and should be zero for the sum.

Answer (score 0):

If `cases`, `po`, and `in` are all one to one relationships, your SQL just needs `GROUP BY cases.case_key`, a unique key/index on `case_key` for the `in`, `po` and `cases` tables, and a little more depending on the version of MySQL you're using and its support for proper functional dependence logic.

```
SELECT cases.case_key
     , po.quantity      -- this is functionally dependent on cases.case_key
     , in.quantity      -- this is functionally dependent on cases.case_key
     , SUM(li.quantity)
  FROM cases
  LEFT JOIN po
    ON cases.case_key = po.case_key
  LEFT JOIN in
    ON cases.case_key = in.case_key
  LEFT JOIN li
    ON cases.case_key = li.case_key
 GROUP BY cases.case_key
;
```

Notice: I joined with `cases.case_key` in all cases because you indicate the other tables may not have a corresponding `case_key` match in all cases.  Your original joins could have problems if `case_key` might be null as a result of any of the joins.  See `outer joins` if you need more detail on that behavior.

If you didn't mean to join with `cases` in your original SQL, just remove that from the query and adjust accordingly.